# Monitoring Eth Transactions and Syncing Native Database transactions with Etherium Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, monitoring

Currently, I have a node.js application which interacts with geth through web sockets. I have a listener,

```
web3.eth.subscribe( 'pendingTransactions', function(err, result) { 

    if(!err) { 
        console.log(result) 
    } 

}) 
.on('data', function(transaction) {  

    console.log( transaction ) 

}
```

This listener is working perfectly fine, but it gives me data whenever any unmined transaction is detected by my geth node.

I know, i can use to and from properties from the transaction details and check if this transaction belongs to my address.

However, I would like to know if there is some way by which i can automatically get pending transactions related to my wallet addresses only like in bitcoin (wallet-notify).

If not, am I thinking the right way that I will need to filter these transactions out myself?

Also, what is the best approach to monitor transactions? What if I somewhow, miss a websocket notification. Now, how can i sync my transactions native database with blockchain database?

It would be great if anybody can share his inputs/experience here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to use this: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter

Comment: I am using websockets api and eth.filter has been removed in latest version.
But I guess, using eth.filter with http api will poll for transactions, which I am trying to avoid here.
Pls correct me if i am wrong.